# how to a read file with inverted exclamation mark?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hdfs

I am trying to read a file in spark.
The file is as below:

```
bash-4.2$ hdfs dfs -cat /bigdatahdfs/datamart/lba/brains_files/INPUT_FILES/trial.txt
name¡class
sagar¡first
```

I tried using below method.

However when I try to view the data as below:

```
scala> fileDF.show

| name??class|
|sagar??first|
```

Could anyone please help.

```
val df = spark.read.
format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
option("header", "true"). // Use first line of all files as header
option("inferSchema", "true"). // Automatically infer data types
option("delimiter", "\u0001").
load("/bigdatahdfs/datamart/lba/brains_files/INPUT_FILES/trial.txt")
```